# How can I add span in spesific form group class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, validation

My html like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    //name
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    //gender
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    //email
    ...
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control">
    ...
</div>
```

My javascript like this :

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    error: function(request, status, error) { 
        if ($('#email').val()) {
            $("#email").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            $(".form-group").append('<span class="error error-server help-block">'+request.responseJSON.email[0]+'</span>');
        } 
    }
    ...
```

If there is an error, I want to add append span to the form group that has email

I tried it that way, but it added in all form groups

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/w0thxhox/

```js
$("#email").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
$("#email").before('<span class="error error-server help-block">request.responseJSON.email[0]</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    //name
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    //gender
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    //email
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control">

</div>
```

I've used `jQuery` .`before` method for placing the response message before `input` `textbox`.

**Reference document:** https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_before.asp

In your scenario,

```
$.ajax({
...
error: function(request, status, error) { 
    if ($('#email').val()) {
        $("#email").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        $("#email").before('<span class="error error-server help-block">'+request.responseJSON.email[0]+'</span>');
    } 
}
```

You can use `jQuery` `.after` method for placing the response after `input` `textbox`.

```
$.ajax({
...
error: function(request, status, error) { 
    if ($('#email').val()) {
        $("#email").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        $("#email").after('<span class="error error-server help-block">'+request.responseJSON.email[0]+'</span>');
    } 
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding span in all `form-group` class.

you need to change this

```
 $(".form-group").append('<span class="error error-server help-block">'+request.responseJSON.email[0]+'</span>');
```

to

```
$("#email").closest('.form-group').append('<span class="error error-server help-block">'+request.responseJSON.email[0]+'</span>');
```